# find duplicated ip in mysql table

Tags: mysql

i have table "users":

```
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  id  |  pid | ipaddress |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  1   |   1  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  2   |   2  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  3   |   2  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  4   |   3  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  5   |   3  | 127.0.0.2 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  6   |   3  | 127.0.0.2 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  7   |   4  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  8   |   4  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
  |  9   |   4  | 127.0.0.1 |
  +------+------+-----------+
```

need to select duplicated ip addresses.

```
if ipaddress > 1 in 'pid' echo 'your ip is repeated 2 times';
if ipaddress > 2 in 'pid' echo 'your ip is repeated 3 times';
else 'your ip is unique';
```

allowed repeated ip in different 'pid'.

Comment: So your IP address would be user input ?

Comment: Is this a website running php?

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty no, i have container with user ip comment $comment['User']['ipaddress'] and i need to find duplicated ip in 'pid' and highlight it wit css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this query:

```
SELECT 
  pid, 
  ipaddress, 
  COUNT(ipaddress) AS ipcount
FROM 
  yourtable
GROUP BY 
  ipaddress, pid
HAVING ipcount > 1
```

this would output the following:

```
pid ipdaddress  ipcount
2   127.0.0.1   2
4   127.0.0.1   3
3   127.0.0.2   2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something as

select

```
pid,
ipaddress,
case 
 when count(*) > 2 then 'ip is repeated more than 2 times'
 when count(*) = 2 then 'ip is repeated 2 times' 
 else 'unique'
end as message
from table_name
group by pid,ipaddress
```

Comment: I did not understand and the image is too small to view. Give some example in to the question.

Comment: If you are looking for duplicate IP irrespective of pid then remove pid from the group by clause.